# Alternative methods for System.gc and ShutdownHook in java

Tags: multithreading, jvm

We are using System.gc method to halt JVM to delete temp directory,because previously it was not getting deleted,but i got to know that using System.gc or  Runtime.getRuntime()  is a bad practice,so I Im thinking to use methods others than this ,kindly suggest which one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage your resources manually instead of relying on finalizers. I.e. delete the temp directory at the end of the method that created it or if you're using asynchronous control flows then add a CompletableFuture to the end that does the removal.
Use try-with-resources statements to ensure that files only remain open within a limited scope.

On posix systems you can simply delete (unlink) files and (rmdir) directories even if they are still referenced by some file descriptors.